# How to use external SVG elements in IE 9-10-11 (<use> tag)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg

I have the following:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="icon">
     <use xlink:href="/img/svg/road.svg#Laag_1"></use>
</svg>
```

My doctype is correct. The SVG is shown when I add it in a general `<img>` tag. The reason why I can't do that is I can't do any animation (eg: fill: #fff;) onto it so this is the only solution.

The icons are properly displayed in all other browsers. Any ideas here?

Comment: Which IE version you are using ?.

Comment: Not supported in IE8 http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg

Comment: Oh indeed that wasn't very clear. It doesn't need to work in IE8. IE10+ (but it's not shown in 10 or 11)

Comment: [This blog](https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-external-source/) says IE9, IE10 and IE11 don't support external use.

Comment: @RobertLongson Found the workaround. Works like a charm. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Found the answer through the comment of Robert Longson)

The problem here is the external use of the use-tag. One way to fix it is to use the **svg4everybody** **library** created by Jonathan.

Github:
https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody

CDN: 
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/svg4everybody

Just implement it in the footer, call the function svg4everybody(); and it does the job. Note that you need the specific markup of the SVG file in order for it to work.

Markup of the SVG image has slightly changed:

```
<svg title="Tower" role="img" class="icon">
    <use xlink:href="/img/svg/_svg-icons.svg#tower"/>
</svg>
```

The "viewbox" is now specified in the general **_svg-icons.svg** file (and the title and role specified for readability)